# ListView: Stretch grid in custom datatemplate to max width?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to create a custom `DataTemplate` for my `ListView`.
I have a simple `class Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public SolidColorBrush SomeColor{get;set;}

    public Person(string name){ Name = name; }
}
```

I set the `ItemsSource` property of my `ListView` to a `List<Person> persons`.
If I just use `DisplayMemberPath=Name` everything works fine but I would like to have a custom template to show `Name` and `SomeColor`.
I created a sample `Grid` to show how I want it to look like (without any bindings, just as an example):

```
<Grid Height="50">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="10"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Patrick" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

This is my try to implement my `DataTemplate` for the `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=FriendList ,Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="10"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="LimeGreen" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The problem is now that the `Grid` does not expand to the full available width of the ListView. It is just a small `Grid` of maybe 20-30px width.
After searching Google I added `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` but it did not help.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try also setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` in your `ItemContainerStyle/Style/Setter`.